# Small error but I don't see where - Symfony Foreign keys

Tags: php, symfony, foreign-keys, key

Hey guys i have an error (i think that i do a really idiot error but i don't see were) trying to waste time i ask you the question. The error is that my foreign keys is incorrectly formed. Cannot be more precise ... Thx to all people who will try to answer or search :p

My UserInterestEntity :

```
/**
* UserInterest
*
* @ORM\Table(name="user_interest", indexes {@ORM\Index(name="userInterest_category_id_fk", columns={"category_id"})})
* @ORM\Entity
*/
class UserInterest
{

/**
 * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Category
 *
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
 private $category;
 }
```

My Category Entity :

```
/**
* UserInterest
*
* @ORM\Table(name="Category", uniqueConstraints {@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="category_id_uindex", columns={"id"})})
* @ORM\Entity
*/
class Category
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="UserInterest", inversedBy="Category")
 */
protected $id;
```

The error is that when i do : php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force tat tells me : Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed

Comment: No one can help you if you can't explain __what__ is wrong.

Comment: when i try to do : php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force tat tells me  :

Comment: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1025 Error on rename of './program/#sql-1112_bc' to './program'(errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relation must not be mapped on the ID but on a separate property. On the category class you can create an userIntrests property defining the userIntrests that have this category. In example:

```
class Category
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="UserInterest", mappedBy="category")
     */
    protected $intrests;
}

class UserIntrest
{
   /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id

    /**

     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="intrests")
     */
    protected $category;
}
```

Use this for reference https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional

Comment: That tells my : [Creation Error] The annotation @ORM\ManyToOne declared on property AppBundle\Entity\UserInterest::$category does not have a property named "mappedBy". Available properties: targetEntit  
  y, cascade, fetch, inversedBy

Comment: Switch the inversed my and mapped by, my fault

Comment: Column name `id` referenced for relation from AppBundle\Entity\Category towards AppBundle\Entity\UserInterest does not exist.

Comment: Sorry, made mistake again. Can you please try again ?

Comment: I have this now xD   Single id is not allowed on composite primary key in entity AppBundle\Entity\UserInterest

Comment: Did you remove the @id annotation from the category property ?

Comment: i have also this entity maybe that ? (that one works well) /**
     * @var \AppBundle\Entity\User
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $user;

Comment: Do you have multiple properties having the @id annotation ?

Comment: Can you try it with only one property having the @id annotation per class. Otherwise you will have to create composite ids, that will take a little bit more effort.

Comment: that put me : /user_interest' (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Comment: You might want to try to delete you current schema using bin/console doctrine:database:drop --force and create it agian.

Comment: Since you tried a lot of different solutions, you might have broken your current schema, so everytime you try something, it might be a good idea to recreate your entire database